# Read through and save files with different filenames

Tags: matlab, for-loop, save

I have a list of CSV files. The filenames of these files have been stored in the form [year '_MDA8_mat.dat']. I want to read in each of these files into MATLAB and save the output. How can I write the code so that each year is considered in turn and the output `.mat` file will be saved for each year?

Here's what I have for reading in one of the files:

```
flist = fopen('2006_MDA8_mat.dat'); % Open the list of file names - CSV files of states with data under consideration

nt = 0; % Counter will go up one for each file loaded
while ~feof(flist) % While end of file has not been reached
    for i = 1:27299 % Number of files 

        fname = fgetl(flist); % Reads next line of list, which is the name of the next data file
        disp(fname); % Stores name as string in fname

        nt = nt+1; % Time index

        load (fname, 'site_data'); % Load current file. It is all the data for one site for one year
        O3_data{i} = site_data;
        % Do some more stuff
end
save ('2006_MDA8_1990_2014.mat', '-v7.3')
```

I tried to write a `for` loop like this:

```
year = 2006:2014
for y = 1:9
    flist = fopen([year(y) '_MDA8_mat.dat']);
    nt = 0; % Counter will go up one for each file loaded
    while ~feof(flist) % While end of file has not been reached
        for i = 1:1500 % Number of files 
           % Same as above   
        end
    end
    save ([year '_MDA8_1990_2014.mat'], '-v7.3')
end
```

However, when I run this, it doesn't do the same thing as it did for the one file script. I'm not quite sure where the error occurs, but MATLAB tells me there's an error with `feof`, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: year is a number and not char. do  save ([num2str(year) '_MDA8_1990_2014.mat'], '-v7.3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When combining numbers and strings, you need to do a `num2str` on the number:

`[num2str(year) '_MDA8_1990_2014.mat']`